# Drag and Drop into Nested Grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, grid

In my view I have grid row expander. Inside that row expander I have a nested grid. I want perform drag and drop operation in it. The main grid drag and drop working fine. But in nested grid, not working. while mouse over on the nested grid it shows not valid drop target.
 I set the drop location in my nested grid after render
 `var featured_targetObj = new Ext.dd.DDTarget(thisObj,'CSRPT' + 'group1');`
 
but nothing positive.. any idea for fix this..[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far achieving this?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: The normal drag and drop and Row Expender are  working.. Now I have nested grid when i try to drop into the nested grid it's not working.. I think issue in setting "dropgroup". but I dont know how to fix this..

Comment: how to set drop zone to nested grid..